# How to take all the properties of a property file as initialized variables inside a java program?

Tags: java, properties, getproperties

I'm using properties file in my java program.

Currently whenever I'm need of some property from properties file, I'm using `propertyFile.getProperty(propertyKeyName);`and taking this into some variable: `String propertyName1 = propertyFile.getProperty(propertyKeyName);`

Is there any way that with out explicitly defining a variable (`propertyName1`) and initializing it using `getProperty()`, Can I get the all the Key=Value of a properties file as String variable which has been initialized "String Key=Value" inside my program?

Thanks,
Chandra

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you expect?

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html in java. It take the input stream and loads all of property as string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Variables are declared at compile-time - their names (for instance/static variables, at least) and types are baked into the class file. How could that possibly work when the names are only known at *execution* time?

What would you expect to happen if wrote an expression which referred to a variable which "didn't exist" at execution time due to the contents of the properties file?

Now what you *can* do is write a class to initialize an instance of a class via reflection - you could write your class:

```
public class Person
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String jobTitle;
    // Whatever... accessors etc
}
```

and then use reflection to create an instance of `Person` with values populated from a properties file. That mechanism could then fail at load time if some properties were missing (if you wanted it to).

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet. As I'm Java begginer, I dont know about the reflections feature. I'll go thro it and try that...

Comment: @merlachandra: If you're a beginner, I'd suggest staying well away from reflection for the moment. Do things the laborious but straightforward way for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Currently I'm continuing with the <code>getProperty()</code> for getting individual properties to my program.